# List of an persisted Object is loaded first after restart

Tags: jpa, persistence, one-to-many

**code**

> class list{
>   @OneToMany(targetEntity=ShoppingItemStatus.class,
>   cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>   private List items = new ArrayList();
>
> }

Hello,

i am working with Eclipse Link and Glassfish and i have got a quite annoying error.

1. I am persisting an Object
2. I am reading out the list of objects (new object is included)
3. The  "items" of he new Object does not contain any items

**Then i restart the Server:**

All items are contained correctly. I can not really understand this error, because in step 2. The data in the table between ShoppingItemStatus and list are existing.

I'm searching two days, changing every Config &Annotation in my entities.

I'm at a loss
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when you are not updating both sides of the relationship.  Because you never add the the OneToMany it is empty when you re-read it.  You need to maintain both sides of the relationship.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side

By default EclipseLink enables a shared cache.  You when you re-read the object it is coming from the cache, and still has the state you persisted as.

You would have this issue in a single entity manager/transaction as well, even without a shared cache.

You could always disable the shared cache to avoid the issue, but you still need to fix your code.

Comment: Ok, thank you. A simple em.clear() killed all days work.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

I tried this, but still there ist this problem, you talked about fixxing my code. What do you mean exactly by this? Thanks!